# Obtain the Viewport Dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched & searched but I seem unable to find a way to get the viewport width & height in JQuery.

From my attempts it seems that the following gives me the dimensions of the whole page(not the view on screen):

```
$(window).width(); $(window).height();
```

Whats the way to the get the dimensions of the viewport?

I am attempting to determine if the user has a window smaller than 800 by 600 pixels(ie, they are on a smart phone). If they are then I position the JQuery UI Dialog within their window rather than in the center of the page/document.

Comment: you're wrong `$(window).width(); $(window).height();` give you the current view-port and `$(document).width(); $(document).height();` gives you the whole page

Comment: @micha it doesn't give the correct values when running on Android 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `screen.width` and `screen.height` instead, it will give the viewport's width and height.