# jQuery: run a function when in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a function when in `div` comes in viewport,
I tried to search it on google but did not found any effective jQuery view port detector plugin.

Please help me for detecting view port using jQuery

Comment: Useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255369/obtain-the-viewport-dimensions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935888/highlight-element-that-is-closest-to-middle-of-viewport, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/how-to-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using

Comment: you suggested answers are for `height()` and `width()` , but my problem is differnt

Comment: I think as @elclanrs was suggesting via links, the way to go is to get the divs offset height from the top of the page, and then compare it to the distance the user has scrolled down the page using .scrollTop() http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: as per suggestions above, you need to check the page on every scroll event, to check whether the *div* (or other element) is now visible.  There is no DOM event that fires when an element is visible, so you're stuck with manually checking.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish is a lot like lazy loading images (only you want to invoke your own custom function).

You can try to investigate [lazyload jQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) or [Lazy-Load-Images-without-jQuery](https://github.com/ezYZ/Lazy-Load-Images-without-jQuery) and carry on from there.